# CSS: Formatting two floating divs within a container

Tags: css

I have a container: divA.

divB and divC are inside divA.

Both divB and divC are floated left, so they are side by side.

```
#divA
height:500px;
width:1000px;

#divB 
width:200px;
height:100%;
float:left;

#divC
height:100%;
float:left;
width:????
```

I want divC to fill the remaining space of divA dynamically, i.e I need it to have a dynamic width. How can I do this?

P.S If I set its width to 100% it fills the entire divA. What I want is for it to fill the entire width of divA but minus divB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `overflow:hidden` to your `#divc` .Write like this:

```
#divB{ 
width:200px;
height:100%;
float:left;
}
#divC{
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/yY388/